# Selenium Webdriver: How to Download a PDF File with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, pdf, download, automation

I am using selenium webdriver to automate downloading several PDF files. I get the PDF preview window (see below), and now I would like to download the file. How can I accomplish this using Google Chrome as the browser?

[image: Dialog Box]

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43471196/3846228)... maybe it'll help you.

Answer (score 43):

Try this code, it worked for me.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"download.default_directory": "C:/Users/XXXX/Desktop", #Change default directory for downloads
"download.prompt_for_download": False, #To auto download the file
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True #It will not show PDF directly in chrome
})
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: Thanks! great answer!

Comment: This didn't work for me until I changed the default directory to use backslash, so instead of "C:/Users/XXXX/Desktop" I use "C:\\Users\\XXXX\\Desktop".

Comment: What is `download.directory_upgrade` for?

Comment: Ordinal0 [0x00A75230+1856048]
 BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76FDFA29+25]
 RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77A37B5E+286]
 RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77A37B2E+238]

Comment: Confirming this works using [Splinter](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elements-in-the-page.html) (based on Selenium) which doesn't do file downloads.

Answer (score 5):

I did it and it worked, don't ask me how :)

```py
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
#"download.default_directory": "C:/Users/517/Download", #Change default directory for downloads
#"download.prompt_for_download": False, #To auto download the file
#"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True #It will not show PDF directly in chrome 
})
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: Ordinal0 [0x00A75230+1856048]
 BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76FDFA29+25]
 RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77A37B5E+286]
 RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77A37B2E+238]

Answer (score 5):

I found this piece of code somewhere on Stackoverflow itself and it serves the purpose for me without having to use selenium at all.

```
import urllib.request

response = urllib.request.urlopen(URL)    
file = open("FILENAME.pdf", 'wb')
file.write(response.read())
file.close()
```

Comment: This method will only work for non-authenticated sessions. It is not robust to websites which require a login. @Kumar's  answer will work for both non-authenticated and authenticated sessions.

Answer (score 3):

You can download the pdf (`Embeded pdf` & `Normal pdf`) from web using selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver

download_dir = "C:\\Users\\omprakashpk\\Documents" # for linux/*nix, download_dir="/usr/Public"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False, "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}], # Disable Chrome's PDF Viewer
               "download.default_directory": download_dir , "download.extensions_to_open": "applications/pdf"}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", profile)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\chromedriver\\chromedriver_2_32.exe', chrome_options=options)  # Optional argument, if not specified will search path.

driver.get(`pdf_url`)
```

It will download and save the pdf in directory specified. Change the `download_dir` location and `chrome driver location` as per your convenience.

You can download chrome driver from [here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/chromedriver_win32.zip).

Hope it helps!

Comment: this works with gui, if I add `options.add_argument('headless') ` it doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: Try `add_argument("--headless")`. It works with python3. I am sure, it will work for python 2 also.

Comment: I'm also using python3. it might be working for other pdf links but for AWS S3 links, it's not working. eg:`http://spark-public.s3.amazonaws.com/nlp/slides/AdvancedMaxent.pdf
`. Even wget doesn't for aws links. I'm not sure how aws checks you whether you are in gui mode or not.

Comment: it seems that 'not allowing' file downloads in headless mode is a security feature  https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481#c39

Comment: @ Om Prakash， have you tested your code with mode of headless chrome?  Because I tested the code from your github page in headless chrome and it didn't work.

Comment: @Om Prakash, If I would like to download an xml?

Answer (score -2):

In My case it worked without any code modification,Just need to disabled the Chrome pdf viewer

Here are the steps to disable it

1. Go into Chrome Settings
2. Scroll to the bottom click on Advanced
3. Under Privacy And Security - Click on "Site Settings"
4. Scroll to PDF Documents
5. Enable "Download PDF files instead of automatically opening them in Chrome"

Answer (score -2):

You can download the PDF file using Python's requests library

```
import requests
pdf_url = driver.current_url       # Get Current URL
response = requests.get(pdf_url)
file_name = 'filename.pdf'
with open(file_name, 'wb') as f:
   f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: I believe this answer was downvoted because the question concerns a website with an embedded PDF (i.e. <embed> tag) where this wouldn't work.  However, I have a use case where the PDF is being displayed in-brower from the website and this answer is a far better solution than using selenium.  I am commenting to note this for any others that see this post.