# Python Download PDF Embedded in a Page

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping

I have this link:

- http://www.equibase.com/premium/chartEmb.cfm?track=ALB&raceDate=06/17/2002&cy=USA&rn=1

I want to download the embedded PDF.

I have tried the normal methods of `urllib` and `request` but they're not working.

```
import urllib2

url = "http://www.equibase.com/premium/chartEmb.cfm?track=ALB&raceDate=06/17/2002&cy=USA&rn=1"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
file = open("document.pdf", 'wb')
file.write(response.read())
file.close()
```

Moreover, I have also tried to find the original link of the pdf but it also did not work.

Internal link:

- http://www.equibase.com/premium/eqbPDFChartPlus.cfm?RACE=A&BorP=P&TID=ALB&CTRY=USA&DT=06/17/2002&DAY=D&STYLE=EQB&eqbPDFChartPlus.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `Selenium` with a specific `ChromeProfile` you can download embedded pdfs using the following code:

**Code:**

```
def download_pdf(lnk):
    
    from selenium import webdriver
    from time import sleep
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    
    download_folder = "C:\\"    
    
    profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False,
                                         "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
               "download.default_directory": download_folder,
               "download.extensions_to_open": "",
               "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}
    
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", profile)
    
    print("Downloading file from link: {}".format(lnk))
        
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
    driver.get(lnk)
    
    filename = lnk.split("/")[4].split(".cfm")[0]
    print("File: {}".format(filename))
    
    print("Status: Download Complete.")
    print("Folder: {}".format(download_folder))
    
    driver.close()
```

**And when I call this function:**

```
download_pdf("http://www.equibase.com/premium/eqbPDFChartPlus.cfm?RACE=1&BorP=P&TID=ALB&CTRY=USA&DT=06/17/2002&DAY=D&STYLE=EQB")
```

**Thats the output:**

```
>>> Downloading file from link: http://www.equibase.com/premium/eqbPDFChartPlus.cfm?RACE=1&BorP=P&TID=ALB&CTRY=USA&DT=06/17/2002&DAY=D&STYLE=EQB
>>> File: eqbPDFChartPlus
>>> Status: Download Complete.
>>> Folder: C:\
```

[image]

---

**Take a look at the specific profile:**

```
profile = {"plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False,
                                     "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
           "download.default_directory": download_folder,
           "download.extensions_to_open": ""}
```

It disables the `Chrome PDF Viewer` plugin (that embedds the pdf at the webpage), set the default download folder to the folder defined at `download_folder` variable and sets that Chrome isn't allowed to open any extensions automatically.

After that, when you open the so called "Internal link" your webdriver will automatically download the `.pdf` file to the `download_folder`.

Comment: The problem of this method is, how to define the file name when downloading the pdf file ?

Comment: @exteral but you can add a few lines of code to rename the last downloaded file at `download_folder`

Comment: @dot.Py how do you find the so called "internal link"?

Comment: im having troubles with this. When i click in save file a prompt for saving the file appears, it requires a name