# How do I press on the "save" button of a print pop up with selenium?

Tags: python, django, selenium

I'm trying to get selenium to press on the save button of the print pop up to save a pdf file. I can get selenium to press on the "print" button but once the pop up appears with the adress chrome://print/ nothing happens.
Is there another way to do it?

This is the part's code so far:

```
        #download pdf
        download_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="printpagetoolbar"]/tbody/tr/td[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/a')))
        download_button.click()

        # download file: Nothing happens, this doesn't work
        download = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="sidebar"]//print-preview-button-strip//div/cr-button[1]'))
        download.click()
```

This is the image of the pop up window:
[image]

Comment: You could just set options to download the pdf.

Comment: What type of options? I tried some and nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

This answer here might help you:
[Selenium Webdriver: How to Download a PDF File with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149534/selenium-webdriver-how-to-download-a-pdf-file-with-python)

as well as:

[Python Download PDF Embedded in a Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470535/python-download-pdf-embedded-in-a-page/43471196#43471196)

Please leave any comments if you have further questions!

Comment: one of the solutions worked for me, but i get a window asking me to give a name to the file and i cant handle it