# Python download href, got the source code instead of a pdf file

Tags: python, selenium, get

I'm trying to download a pdf file with the following href (i change some value cause the pdf contain personal information)

```
https://clients.direct-energie.com/grandcompte/factures/consulter-votre-facture/?tx_defacturation%5BdoId%5D=857AD9348B0007984D4B128F1E8BE&cHash=7b3a9f6d109dde87bd1d95b80ca1d
```

When i past this href in my browser the pdf file is directly download, but when i'm trying to use request in my python code its only download the source code of

```
https://clients.direct-energie.com/grandcompte/factures/consulter-votre-facture/
```

Here is my code, i use selenium to find the href in the website

```
fact = driver.find_element_by_xpath(url)
href = fact.get_attribute('href')
print(href)      // href is correct here
reply = get(href, Stream=True)
print(reply)     // I got the source code
```

Here is the html find by selenium

```
<a href="grandcompte/factures/consulter-votre-factue/?tx_defacturation%5BdoId%5D=857AD9348B0007984D4B128F1E8BE&cHash=7b3a9f6d109dde87bd1d95b80ca1d"></a>
```

I hope you have enough informations to help, Thx

Comment: Can you rephrase the question about what exactly you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't use your link because it required auth so found another example of a redirecting pdf download. Setting Chrome to download the pdf instead of displaying it taken from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48705180/7069140).

```
import selenium.webdriver

url = "https://readthedocs.org/projects/selenium-python/downloads/pdf/latest/"

download_dir = 'C:/Dev'
profile = {
    "plugins.plugins_list": [{"enabled": False, "name": "Chrome PDF Viewer"}],
    "download.default_directory": download_dir ,
    "download.extensions_to_open": "applications/pdf"
}

options = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", profile)
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get(url)
```

From looking at the docs, the `driver.get` method doesn't return anything, it's just telling the webdriver to navigate to a page. If you want to handle the pdf in Python before saving it to a file then perhaps look at using [Requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) or [Robobrowser](https://robobrowser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html).

`Stream=True` option wasn't available for `webdriver.Chrome` so not sure if this is the method you were using but the above should do what you want.