# Python / Selenium downloading a PDF with Firefox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver

In my code, I am using Firefox as my browser for navigating to a site, conducting a search, and then clicking to view each pdf document.  Once in the document (it loads without giving me a prompt to download it), I would like to download the document.  I found a Java version of how to do this, but it doesn't work as easily in Python.  I am also trying below to pick the element from the Adobe framework (to download it directly, but once again, it cannot find the xpath object).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import requests, time


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver")
driver.get("https://www.okcc.online/")
driver.maximize_window()
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/Users/username/Desktop/oklahoma/oklahoma_county")
options.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", "true")
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
options.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", "true")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='rod-menu-button']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='rodDocTypeTxt']"))).send_keys('MTG')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='ui-id-1']//li//div"))).click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rod-date-toggle"]').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rodFromDateTxt"]').send_keys('4/1/2020')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rodToDateTxt"]').send_keys('4/20/2020')

search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rod-submit-search"]').click()

time.sleep(2)

pdf = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".icon.pdf-icon")

for i in pdf:
    i.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    download_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="download"]')
    download_button.click()
    close_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pdf-function-button.pdf-close')
    close_button.click()
```

Comment: You have two issues. First, the PDF popup takes some time to load. You should use webdriver.wait to wait until the new iframe is present. Second, the PDF popup is in an iframe. You need to switch to that iframe before finding the download button. Note you will need to switch back out of the iframe when you are done with it before going to the next PDF

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Webdriver: How to Download a PDF File with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149534/selenium-webdriver-how-to-download-a-pdf-file-with-python)

Comment: Not really.  It is for Chrome, and not Firefox

Comment: In this case, how do you select the iframe?  I tried selecting it but it doesn't register.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 3):

Probably you have already solved this problem, but your question helped me to solve the same problem that I was facing.

You just need to put the part "driver = webdriver.Firefox" after "options.set_preference", and add options argument in the webdriver.Firefox.

Besides that, you need change the part:

```
options.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", "true")
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
options.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", "true")
```

for:

```
options.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
options.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
```

Below there is my code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import requests, time



options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/Users/username/Desktop/oklahoma/oklahoma_county")
options.set_preference("browser.download.useDownloadDir", True)
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
options.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options = options, executable_path="geckodriver")
driver.get("https://www.okcc.online/")
driver.maximize_window()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='rod-menu-button']"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='rodDocTypeTxt']"))).send_keys('MTG')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='ui-id-1']//li//div"))).click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rod-date-toggle"]').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rodFromDateTxt"]').send_keys('4/1/2020')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rodToDateTxt"]').send_keys('4/20/2020')

search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rod-submit-search"]').click()

time.sleep(2)

pdf = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".icon.pdf-icon")

for i in pdf:
    i.click()
    time.sleep(3)
    download_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="download"]')
    download_button.click()
    close_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.pdf-function-button.pdf-close')
    close_button.click()
```