# How to automatically download a PDF file with selenium in python when it is open on another browser page

Tags: python, selenium

I am clicking an  link with selenium and it is opening a new browser tab with a PDF, I want to know if there is a way to dowload that PDF , I don't care if the browser tab is open and then the downloading is started, what I want is to download that PDF.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149534/selenium-webdriver-how-to-download-a-pdf-file-with-python Should be many repeats.

Comment: Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 1):

you can use pyautogui and Options

```
import pyautogui
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

DRIVER_PATH = r'chromedriver.exe'  //chromedriver path
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs', {
"download.default_directory": "C:/Users", #Change default directory for downloads
"download.prompt_for_download": False, #To auto download the file
"download.directory_upgrade": True,
"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True #It will not show PDF directly in chrome
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH,options = chrome_options)
driver.get(url) //url of pdf
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.press('enter')
```