# Cannot download pdf file using selenium on python

Tags: python, selenium

How to download PDF file using Selenium on Python

I have tried

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            prefs = {
                "download.prompt_for_download": False, # To auto download the file
                "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True # It will not show PDF directly in chrome
                    }
            options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
```

But it does not work for me, the pdf file on the bottom tab is "Failed - Download Error"
I'm using version:

- Python: 3.8.12
- Selenium: 4.1.0
- Chromedriver: 97.0.4692 google-chrome (using webdriver-manager for auto detecting Chrome version)

Please help!

Comment: This might of help to you  [SO Archive Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149534/selenium-webdriver-how-to-download-a-pdf-file-with-python)

Comment: Please share all your relevant code, not only driver options settings. Including the link to the page you are working on