# Selenium [JavaScript] - Find elements under embedded element with Shadow DOM [ #shadow-root (user-agent) ]

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to click elements of shadow dom elements.

```
var propelement = await wdriver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="rptLoadingFrame"]'));
var pdf_url = await propelement.getAttribute('src')
wdriver.get(pdf_url);
//var download1  = await wdriver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="download"]'));
//download1.click();

await wdriver.executeScript("document.querySelector('#viewer').shadowRoot.querySelector('#toolbar').shadowRoot.querySelector('#downloads').shadowRoot.querySelector('#download').shadowRoot.querySelector('#icon').click()");
```

Getting below error message

> JavascriptError: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shadowRoot')

1. PDF viewer is embedded within iframe and no DOM visible accept <slot> element inside Embed element with #Shadow Root (user-agent)

   [image]
2. When I access SRC mentioned in iframe got below DOM i.e. PDF viewer. I want to click "Download" button to download the PDF.

   [image]

Comment: Try something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54427220/2851311. I know this is for Python, but you should be able to convert it to Javascript. I have not tried myself, but at least one other person commented on the thread that it worked.

Comment: Below capabilities working fine except **download.default_directory**.
'options.setUserPreferences({'download.default_directory': "C:\\Downloads"});'
`options.setUserPreferences({'download.prompt_for_download': false});`
`options.setUserPreferences({'download.directory_upgradeoad': true});`
`options.setUserPreferences({'plugins.always_open_pdf_externally': true});`. Kindly help in changing path.