# Download PDF Using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Using Selenium and Python, how can I click the download button? I don't see anything in the documentation located here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html so I am not sure where to begin.

[image: Download Button on PDF]

This download button is at the very top of the screen, I am viewing a pdf.

The URL looks like this: is [https://.../...pdf](https://Not%20an%20actual%20link,%20just%20showing%20what%20it%20looks%20like)

Comment: Where exactly do you see this download button? We need more info. such as HTML in text

Comment: Edited my post, please let me konw if you need more clarification.

Comment: if you want do download using selenium only take a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149534/selenium-webdriver-how-to-download-a-pdf-file-with-python

Answer (score 1):

you can use the url itself to download the file

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://...url.pdf", "name.pdf")
```