# How to click a pdfviewer download button in shadowroot(open) with selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-crawler, shadow-dom

I'm accessing this url (https://cissearch.kcc.gov.tw/System/Bulletin/View.aspx?BulletinSN=239928&pages=9957#pdfStart) with selenium in python, and I'm trying to click on the download button in the pdfviewer.

I've tried adding options as suggested here: [Selenium Webdriver: How to Download a PDF File with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149534/selenium-webdriver-how-to-download-a-pdf-file-with-python)

But I end up with a page with an `open` button that I still have to manually click to download the pdf file.

I've also tried this route https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/shadow-dom-in-selenium but I was unable to locate any element.

So I'm trying to click on the button with this:

```py
driver.execute_script("document.querySelector('pdf-viewer').shadowRoot.querySelector('viewer-toolbar').shadowRoot.querySelector('viewer-download-controls').shadowRoot.querySelector('cr-action-menu').querySelector('button')")
```

This javascript works in the devtools console as shown in this image:

[image]

but it returns this error when I run it in python

```bash
JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'shadowRoot')
  (Session info: chrome=109.0.5414.87)
```

Comment: Have you googled something like "selenium shadowroot"? Top result for me is [How To Automate Shadow DOM In Selenium WebDriver](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/shadow-dom-in-selenium/) which talks about [`getShadowRoot()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getShadowRoot()).

Comment: Yes I have tried that route. I am unable to locate any element in the url I posted in the question.

Comment: Part of asking is showing what you tried. Edit your question to also include your attempts using `getShadowRoot`.

Comment: Also, you won't be able to access any shadow DOM using `execute_script` since this runs the javascript in the page's context and the page's javascript can't access shadow DOMs.

Comment: if you are able to open the viewer page, you can have this to click the download button `driver.execute_script("document.getElementById("download").click()")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the url does not actually point to a pdf file. It's a webpage with an embedded pdf viewer.

By running this I was able to get the actual url to the pdf file:

```py
pdf_url = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe').get_attribute("src")
```

and then I can just download it with this

```py
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(pdf_url, "test.pdf")
```

Comment: SOmehow I see an error as: _raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1122)>_