# Why is Selenium unable to access a website? it seems to be constantly loading

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Why can't I use selenium to enter this website "https://ir.baidu.com/static-files/b7b97cfa-f30b-48ba-8702-e5edb2767b21", which is Baidu's third quarter financial result? my code is basically:

```py
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

browser.get("https://ir.baidu.com/financial-reports")

download_link = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@title="BIDU 3Q22 ER v2.pdf"]')

download_link.click()
```

Below is what I am seeing after the "download_link.click()" line

[image]

Comment: You haven't said what **the actual problem** is.  Does the site not load?  Does the browser freeze?  Do you get an error message?

Comment: Hi John Gordon sorry about that, I have added in a screenshot of the problem I am seeing. The issue here is that my browser seems to be unable to load the webpage after the "download_link.click()" line

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not suffice the exact root cause, based on the ask I have one query.

> Where exactly the code is stuck/not working?
>
> 1. Is it stuck at Page loading  -> We need to analize if we are able to hit the URL within the session period and code does not went
>    through.
> 2. Is it stuck before DOM loaded  -> We need to verify our code should reach the URL and setup the testbed for next operation once DOM
>    is perfectly loaded and visible.
> 3. Is it stuck after DOM loaded but page empty (not possible - taking it for if API issue)  -> We need to check console logs what happens in
>    the background if page is empty.

Most of the web apps are using AJAX techniques. When a page is loaded by the browser, the elements within that page may load at different time intervals. This makes locating elements difficult: if an element is not yet present in the DOM, a locate function will raise an *ElementNotVisibleException* exception for this we need to implement the code with *try-catch-finally*.

Most probable scenario from your code-snippet, it looks similar to the case-2 (upto my understanding).

**Solution:**

We need to make sure our code reach step-by-step on each operation it performs (since its not human) we need to instruct, observe and prevent the automation glitchies (@ max extent).

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://ir.baidu.com/financial-reports")
```

Above part is ok!, we need to make sure of below things once we executed above successfully.

> - Page should get loaded successfully.
> - Page should have the Data visible.
> - Page should have the element which we're searching is visible/enabled for click.
> - Execute/Perform the Click on Element.

And for acheiving above steps we have two major [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) under Selenium Webdrive.

Using waits, we can solve this issue. Waiting provides some slack between actions performed - mostly locating an element or any other operation with the element.

```
# Initialise Explicit wait with 30 secs timeout
# This will waits till 30 secs for element and raises exceptions on failure if not visible or found.
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
```

For verifying [financial-reports](https://ir.baidu.com/financial-reports) page is loaded successfully

> Construct XPATH / CSS for searching main page element by any relavent tags ID, CLASS, Title, Text, etc.

```
# Constructed xpath for the main data table for financial-report
page_xpath = '//*[contains(text(), "Download PDF")]/parent::div//following-sibling::div[@class="nir-widget--content"]'

# Wait for 30 secs to get page loaded
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, page_xpath)))
```

Same do it for the PDF element where you want to perform the click.

Combined Code Snippet for example: (solution)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://ir.baidu.com/financial-reports")

# Initialise Explicit wait with 30 secs timeout
# This will waits till 30 secs for element and raises exceptions on failure if not visible or found
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)

try:
  # Constructed xpath for the main data table for financial-report
  page_xpath = '//*[contains(text(), "Download PDF")]/parent::div//following-sibling::div[@class="nir-widget--content"]'

  # Wait for 30 secs to get page loaded
  wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, page_xpath)))

  # Once page is loaded search and wait for element where we need to click.
  q3_report_xpath = '//*[contains(text(), "2022")]/ancestor::article//*[@class="file-link"]//a[contains(@title, "BIDU 3Q22 ER v2.pdf")]'

  # Wait till 30 secs to get Q3 Report element to be clickable or visible.
  element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, q3_report_xpath)))

  # Perform click on element
  element.click()
finally:
  browser.quit()
```

> **Note:** Moreover, you can also enhance the code by constructing CSS/XPATH more dynamically instead of searching for exact PDF names.

Comment: Hi Riyaz Khan, I tried your steps but it does not work

Comment: @Jason, I've looked into the screenshot. Can you able to log the network logs when a click is processed? Seems like its an BE failure, but its more over the waits (I believe). Moreover, can you place a sleep after click is processed? just to ensure we are waiting for API to get executed in that time-frame. Also, we have Synchronous and Async requests that needs to manage on our end. So far I'm seeing below error after processing click.
`caught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received`

Comment: Also, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43149534/selenium-webdriver-how-to-download-a-pdf-file-with-python) might helps.